# NoClassDefFoundError during class load for BLE scanning callback

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am keep on getting the `NoClassDefFoundError` when my class is loaded.

The code is taken from **BluetoothLeGatt** project -

http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/project.html

**My code:**

```
// Device scan callback.
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = 
    new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() { //java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError...

    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, 
    final int rssi, final byte[] scanRecord) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {             
                String msg= device.getAddress();

                Log.d(TAG,msg);
                addItems(msg);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Someone suggested that the error is because my device doesn't support BLE but I want to get rid of this error for any device. So if it doesn't support BLE feature then simply skip this error else continue with the call to this `BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback`.

**NOTE:**

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23221586/bluetooth-low-energy-device-scanning-failed-with-an-exception) my previous SO post for more clarification.

Putting the BLE feature check as the first line onCreate() doesn't stop the crash --

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (!bleCheck()) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.ble_not_supported,  
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          finish();
    }

        //Rest of the code
        //Call to BLE Scan on button click that causes error..
    }



 private boolean bleCheck() {
        boolean result = false;     
        if (getPackageManager().
            hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)){
             result = true;
        }
        return result;
      }
```

Comment: hope the answer helps, BLE for Android is quite tricky as of now, been working on it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As `BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback` was **Added in API level 18** ; [Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback.html), this code would need a API level check also. Here's how i have gone about this, not declared the callback as private but under the condition:

```
boolean apiJBorAbove = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2 ? true
                : false;

boolean isBleAvailable = getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE) ? true : false;


// Use this check to determine whether BLE is supported on the device.
if (isBleAvailable && apiJBorAbove) {
// Initializes a Bluetooth adapter.
// For API level 18 and above, get a reference to
// BluetoothAdapter through BluetoothManager.
final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
            mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

// Ensures Bluetooth is available on the device and it is enabled.
// If not, displays a dialog requesting user permission to enable
// Bluetooth.
if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                startActivity(new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE));
            }

BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = 
    new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, 
                    final int rssi, final byte[] scanRecord) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {             
                                String msg= device.getAddress();
//                              Log.d(TAG,msg);
//                              addItems(msg);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                };
        }
```

The `NoClassDefFoundError` is due to the API , not on the basis of `PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE`.

Comment: Ah, Man thanks a lot. You don't know how much time you saved.

Comment: welcome, glad it helped, let me know if you get stuck with anything else

Comment: Sure, BLE in android is very new to me. Will let you know if stuck. Thanks!

Comment: I stuck at sending commands over BLE. Let me know if you can help at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23393010/how-to-send-data-over-a-bluetooth-low-energy-ble-link

Comment: check my answer and the reference project, will help you understand that