# How to send command to BLE device and show result

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, gatt

```
@Override
public void onServicesDiscovered(final BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
    super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
    if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
        List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristics = null;
        List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
        //I am getting all services
        for (final BluetoothGattService service : services) {
            characteristics = service.getCharacteristics();
            //I am getting all characteristics for each services
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to connect with BLE device and I am getting all services and characteristics, now I have send some commands, like to turn on LED light I have to send "read slonn:" command and in response light will be ON, so how to do that and some time I also have to show current on my UI show for that command is like  "read batti:", show how can I get current value and show my UI dashboard.

Please, help me I am totally do not know how to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to look at the documentation for the device you are trying to connect to and send the command to the proper service with the correct characteristic UID. I would check to see if the device happens to have a sample android program.

Comment: so how to send the command by using  writeCharacteristics or by different way

Comment: With e `write()` method

Comment: Is there any function write() in GATT connection for characteristics , if it is there then please share link .

Comment: I'm also experiencing difficulties with this. I don't know how to send simple one-off commands as ByteArrays, i.e. "cmdg", because it seems that the way BLE works is you can only read and write specific values to characteristics. They're effectively variables. I think you would have to modify the code on the device itself to anticipate changes to those characteristics and then execute some function as a result. If you figure out how to do this please let me know!