# How to send large text over Bluetooth low energy

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have to send large text towards the server, but each time single packet is coming on the server. 
I have to send commands and data to the server and vice versa, I can send commands but no data. Already looked over for several threads but unable to send a large text. Using Android device as server and client.

Can someone please share any working example.

Few More informations
1) Large data ranges 0- 10KB
2) Min Android OS 4.4

Let me add one Possible Example;
Suppose I have a Standalone Music player with a remote app in Android.
I started a playlist of 100 Songs (All songs are on Player not on Android, So Not using RFCOMM for streaming).
I remotely can place any commands like play/ pause/ Next/ Prev/ Vol+/ Vol- etc. 
But List of songs should be sent on Player from remote (This is the part where data suppose to be huge) 
Once players started with Playlist, my phone can be undiscoverable or out of the range or all possible cases to not communicating with the player. Meanwhile, I can Manually operate player, but same should be reported somewhere locally.
Once again I will connect with Player,  Both will sync and share logs.

Comment: Already tried as discribd in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23393010/how-to-send-data-over-a-bluetooth-low-energy-ble-link

Comment: Any reason not to use standard Bluetooth as it's far easier and quicker that way.  BTLE is not designed to do this sort of thing.

Comment: I am trying to do this because large data will be transferred occasionally, but commands will be used to sync devices.
Once a command is fired portable device may still work for hrs continuously without reconnect.